# Segfault using htop on AWS Sagemaker pytorch-1.10-cpu-py38 app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, conda, amazon-sagemaker, htop

I am trying to launch the htop command in the Pytorch 1.10 - Python 3.8 CPU optimized AWS Sagemaker container. This works fine in other images I have used till now, but in this one, the command fails with a segfault:

```
htop 
htop: /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by htop) 
htop: /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by htop) 
htop: /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by htop) 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

More info :

```
htop --version
htop: /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by htop)
htop: /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by htop)
htop: /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by htop)
htop 2.2.0 - (C) 2004-2019 Hisham Muhammad
Released under the GNU GPL.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this with

```bash
# Note: add sudo if needed:
ln -fs /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6 /opt/conda/lib/libncursesw.so.6
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my life after days of searching! This also works if you use `watch` plus `nvidia-smi`, if that helps anyone :P