# htop segmentation fault (core dumped) without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, htop

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

If I directly run `htop`, I'll get

```
[1]    2368661 segmentation fault (core dumped)  htop
```

But with `sudo`, it works normally.

How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try doing `strace htop` and see if any issue stands out. https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-strace-command/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097417 links may help you.